# Rsync resulting in almost a full TB of extra data being transferred

Tags: rsync

I'm currently in the process of transferring what should have been about 2.7TB of data to a 5TB backup disk. Everything looks like it has been going smoothly, except for one thing. The fact that my three 1TB source disks have apparently transferred 3.7TB of data so far and it's still going...

That doesn't add up. All three sources and the destination are Mac OS Extended (with one of the sources being non-journaled, but that finished destination folder is still showing equivalent data amounts with the source disk).

Does anyone know a potential cause of this, or what could be going on? Even if the sources were full to the brim how am I receiving almost a whole TB of extra data when going between same filesystems?

This last source disk is sitting at about 300/899GB transferred so there is still another 600GB to move, pushing the eventual total above 4TB from 3 x 1TB source disks. I'm so confused...

Comment: If it is still in progress, it could be that it is creating reserving the space with temporary files that will eventually be deleted. Have you tried checking what is being copied to see where the space is going to?

Comment: @MichaelB As far as checking I've just been opening the "Get Info" on both the source disk and the folder it was copied to and comparing the "Used: x bytes" information. The backup disk as a whole is what is saying "Used: 3.7TB," though if creating temporary "reserved" space is part of the sync process that could be it. I've always done my transfers in smaller chunks where the data matched +/- 5GB from excluded .Trash, etc. This much of a variance is just very puzzling.

Comment: @MichaelB yeah it finished and is still sitting at 4.2TB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been caused by `rsync` full-copying symlinks. Adding `-a --no-links` or `-a --no-l` solves the issue.

ref: https://serverfault.com/a/233682